# Can my personal iPhone be wiped remotely via Exchange ActiveSync?

Tags: exchange, iphone, ios, remote-control, wipe

I have an `iPhone 7 Plus`.  I connect to the corporate Exchange Server (via Outlook 365) using the plain Exchange account settings (under Passwords & Accounts).

In other words, I have not installed any VPN software or anything like that.  My phone is about as basic as can be.

I connect to the Exchange server using a username and password with a URL of `outlook.office365.com`.  Nothing else.

I've been told by corporate that they have the ability to remotely wipe my phone.  I don't see how but I'm not an expert.  When I log into the web portal of Outlook and go to Mobile Devices, I also see an icon that says it can wipe my phone.

My concern is that this is a personal phone that I pay myself and some rookie IT admin could accidentally wipe my phone.  Which is a major invasion of privacy.  I connect to my corporate email account (at their request) using this "generic" connection.

So my question is, can they really wipe my phone if they chose to?  I've asked for verification on this but I cannot seem to get a real answer from them.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how this if off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading the documentation on this feature correctly, then if the account is added as a system-wide account, the answer is yes. If you are just using the Outlook app and have your Exchange account signed in only on that app, then an ActiveSync wipe will destroy all data for the app only:

> With Outlook for iOS and Android, a remote wipe is done on the Outlook app itself, and does not trigger a full device wipe

(from [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/outlook-for-ios-and-android/manage-devices?view=exchserver-2019) on the Outlook App for Exchange)

If it's a system-wide account, then all data on the device will be lost:

> This procedure will clear all data on the mobile phone, including installed applications, photos, and personal information.

(from [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/exchange-activesync/remote-wipe?view=exchserver-2019) on Exchange ActiveSync)